# How to adjust butt hinge that won't close all the way?

Tags: repair, cabinets, hinges

An old piece of furniture I have has some kind of butt hinge that doesn't close all the way. When I try to close it, the outer part collides with the corner of the inner hinge piece, something that's even more evident by a slight bend caused to the outer piece being forced into the inner one.

(click to enlarge)

[image]
[image]

Other hinges in the furniture close just fine without rubbing up against each other:

[image]

but I can't see any way to adjust the hinge to prevent the one that won't close all the way from rubbing up against the interior piece. Is there a way to adjust these kinds of hinges? Or do I need to get a new hinge to fix the door?

Comment: It looks like the hinge is bent - if so, and you can remove it you can try to straighten it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the hinge, put it into a vice, with the pin part out on top. Use a piece of wood or a wide drift, and tap that protruding part until the plate is at one side. To straighten it all out. If you want to be certain that's the way, take off another hinge that does 'work' properly, and compare the two.

Comment: Hammering it into shape worked wonderfully. Thanks!